# Filter and Join Database Tables in Spring Batch ItemReader

Tags: mysql, spring, jpa, spring-batch

I'm familiar with the concept of batch jobs in Spring, but I have only used it in simple scenarios where one `repository` is used that manages one simple entity. Also, in these scenarios i have used a file as input source and a database table as output destination. Now I need to do the exact opposite with complex entities.

### What's the plan

The batch job gets two parameters of `LocalDateTime` that spans up a time interval. Lets call them `timeParam1` and `timeParam2`.

I have two tables **TableA** and **TableB**.

- `TableB` has a column thats the foreign key of `TableA` called `ID`
- `TableB` has a column thats a `LocalDateTime`, lets call it `TIME`

Now, in the first phase of my batch job i need to do the following:

1. `SELECT * FROM TableA a JOIN TableB b ON a.ID = b.ID` in order to merge all records of `TableB` that belong to a specific record of `TableA`.
2. Filter those rows out where `TIME` is not in the given time interval.
3. Return all records of `TableA` that are contained in the remaining result set. Each record should only be returned once, so if recordA has multiple recordB's that match the criteria, recordA should not be returned multiple times. On the java side the final result should be returned as a list of usable entity objects `List<A>`

The Processor would then turn each `A` Object in the list into a `List<String>` and the writer would be responsible for writing those strings into a file, each on one line.

In one SQL query this would probably be

```sql
SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE nr IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT a.nr FROM TableA a JOIN TableB b ON a.ID = b.ID 
     WHERE timeParam1<= b.TIME AND b.TIME <= timeParam2
```

`nr` is just an attribute of TableA.

I tried to do this with `Spring Batch API` but failed to get this done. Could anybody give some advice on how i should approach this?

Comment: You already have the query in 1 why write a sql one? Something like `SELECT DISTINCT a FROM TABLEA a WHERE a.b.TIME BETWEEN :timeParam1 AND :timeParam2`. Why should the JPA query be more complex than that. If that doesn't work (probably doesn't because B is a collection) please add your entities for more help).

Comment: The problem is actually not the query, but how i can execute it. I know in Batch Processing with Spring you use `repository`s in order to query the datasource but those only manage one specific entity. In my problem statement i need to query two tables, so more entities are involved. What do i need in this case?

Comment: Your understanding is wrong. Also you don't need a repository you can do it with a plain entity manager. But as stated please show your entities (as you mention JPA you should have those, and please mention entities not tables!).